# Iterate re.compile in python to find data between two strings using a list

Tags: python, regex, text-files, data-extraction

I am trying to extract data between different strings from a text file. The code that works for me is:

```
file = open('col1.txt', 'r')
data = file.read()
file.close()
block = re.compile(
r"C1C1"
"(.*?)"
"(C1C2)",
re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
data_block = [result[1] for result in re.findall(block, data)]
output = open('output1.csv', 'w')
for data_new in data_block:
    data_list = data_new.split('\n')
    for x in data_list:
        component = x.split()
        for comp in component:
            output.write(comp + ',')
        output.write('\n')
```

It returns data between strings "C1C1" and "C1C2". I have a list of such strings in my file:

> Cycles = ['C1C1', 'C1C2', 'C1C3',.....]

and I want to iterate the code using this list through a for loop to extract data from my file between all these tags. What I am trying to do is to create an Excel workbook with different sheets containing data for each cycle.

This is the data Structure

> C1C1
>
> Column 1 Column2 Column3 Column4 ....
>
> Column 1 Column2 Column3 Column4 ....
>
> Column 1 Column2 Column3 Column4 ....
>
> C1C2

*Note: I am very beginner in Python so there might also be ways to improve my code and make it more efficient.*

Any help shall be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why not just split your string on `Cycles`? Or split on regex `C1C\d` (or similar)?

Comment: @ctwheels you mean using .split()? Where do you mean?

Comment: agapanthus your text file, depends on the contents, but either create a for loop over the array or straight up split the whole text file using your array

Comment: @ctwheels I have added the data structure. There are many C1C* and I want to iterate between each C1C* and C1C*+1.

Comment: then just do a loop and generate the split strings

Comment: That's what I am trying to do. I just want C1C1 and C1C2 in re.compile to change using "for cycle in cycles" loop over the re.compile.

Comment: You don't need regex, just generate `'C1C'+i` and `'C1C'+(i+1)` in your loop and get their indices, then substring it